# Total Sum of quantities - Excel BOM - Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tree, byte-order-mark

I have this level BOM in Excel. I would like to get the total sum of each item in the BOM by using Python and Pandas.

data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
'Item': ['1','1.1','1.2','1.3','1.3.1','1.3.2','2','2.1','2.1.1','2.1.2','2.2','2.3'],
'QTY': ['2','1','2','1','1','2','3','2','1','5','2','1']
}

data = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Item','QTY'])
```

First I get the parent Item by using rpartition:

```
data['Parent']=data.Item.str.rpartition('.')[0]
```

If 'Parent Item' is null then use the QTY

```
if data.Parent.isnull():
    data ['Total QTY'] = data.QTY
```

Else use the parents Total QTY and multiply it with the QTY

```
else:
    data ['Total Qty'] = data.QTY*"Parent".Total QTY
```

Is there anybody who can help with this issue?

Comment: Hi @Benis, could you show us the code you got so far?

Comment: Hi, Paul, I have updated my question, so I think it makes more sense...